# Chrome: CSS mouse cursor not rendering properly

Tags: google-chrome

Not sure if I should be posting this question here.

But I have suspected Chrome has a rendering issue. This is something that I just noticed today. It is either my browser or Chrome browsers in general.

I am on OSX Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 (64-bit).

The mouse cursor has been changed using CSS to a transparent PNG file.

If you go on http://framerjs.com/examples/ and click on any examples, do you have the same mouse cursor rendering problem? It is rendered properly on other browsers.

[image]

Comment: Ah, the irony of making a website specifically for Chrome, and not making it fully compatible.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara So it is not rendered properly for you on Chrome as well? It only happens today.

Comment: Yeah, not rendering properly in Chrome, but fine in Safari.

Comment: The image itself draws alright though: http://projects.framerjs.com/static/examples/glances.framer/framer/images/cursor.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cursor to show up for Chrome use the CSS below.

```
cursor: -webkit-grab; cursor: -moz-grab;
```

-webkit for Chrome

-moz for Firefox

Reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/